# How can I create Zapier Form Submission then Send Email

Tags: forms, gmail, send, zapier, submission

Good day!

I want to create a Zapier Integration that does:

- Trigger: Form Submission
- Action: Send Email to Gmail for example

I managed to create the integration: https://prnt.sc/tne635
but what's the next step?
How can I test it?

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've created an integration, you can select it in the Zap Editor and create a Zap with it. Your trigger and action can be connected to each other or two any of the other integrations Zapier provides.

That said, Zapier already connects to a number of email and form providers. So if you want to use this for actual work, you're probably better off going with an external service.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it and reply here when I resolve the issue.